# Fingerprints not Taken for Spanish Long Term Visa

Tags: student-visa, spain, egyptian-citizens

I applied for Spanish long term visa for study purpose. In the application day the officer took my papers then they took a picture of me (using their installed camera).
There was a fingerprint machine beside the camera but I wasn't asked to give my fingerprints.

After the visa processing period had passed I went to the embassy and received my passport with the visa (type D) stamped on it. The officer gave me the passport and went inside so I assumed that this was all (they didn't say any single word).

Now I'm not sure if it's OK that my fingerprints was not taken. Does anyone has experience with this type of Visa ? Should I contact them to ask about this ?

Comment: Have you given biometrics for a Schengen visa previously?

Comment: @Traveller No, I've never given my biometrics for a Schengen visa before

Comment: The fingerprint reader may have been there for a different purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I applied for and received a type D visa for Austria just a couple of months ago. My procedure was a bit different than yours. I walked in, handed them my application with all documents, including a passport photo I brought in, and then took fingerprints. I would definitely contact the consulate to make sure they didn't unintentionally skip this. Note: I am a visa-exempt traveler for short stays, this was my first schengen visa.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I contacted embassy of Spain. They responded saying that fingerprints are not required for my type of visa. Looks like the process is different for each country.

Comment: Mm got it! Maybe it's because mine is study and employment? Anyway, glad everything is good! Cheers